# Cómo traslapar div con z -index en css

Tags: html, css

Debo realizar un diseño donde tengo cuatro div que se traslapan entre sí en las esquinas utilizando `position` y `z-index`, pero no logro conseguir que se traslapen sino 3 quedando uno por fuera. Ya utilicé las diferentes combinaciones de `z-index`.
Adjunto imagen de cómo deben quedar posicionados los div. [image: Adjunto como debe quedar al final el diseño],

Adjunto mi html y css:

```css
#contenedor {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.cuadro {
  width: 215px;
  height: 230px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#div1 {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #00D8FF;
  z-index: 10;
}

#div2 {
  margin-top: -93px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #25FE01;
  border-radius: 2px;
  z-index: 8;
}

#div3 {
  margin-top: -93px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  background-color: #F7FE00;
  z-index: 7;
}

#div4 {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 53px;
  background-color: #FE69F9;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <div id="div1" class="cuadro"></div>
  <div id="div2" class="cuadro"></div>
  <div id="div3" class="cuadro"></div>
  <div id="div4" class="cuadro"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debido al comportamiento cíclico de los cuadros, es imposible hacer lo que deseas solo con `z-index` pero puedes lograrlo de otra manera. El truco está en utilizar un pseudo elemento en el cuadrado azul que se superponga al cuadrado verde:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usando un pseudoelemento `::after` quedaría:

```css
#contenedor {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.cuadro {
    width: 215px;
    height: 230px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#div1 {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #00D8FF;
}

#div1::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #00D8FF;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    margin: 0 0 -2px -2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#div2 {
    margin-top: -93px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background-color: #25FE01;
    border-radius: 2px;
    z-index: 4;
}

#div3 {
    margin-top: -93px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    background-color: #F7FE00;
    z-index: 2;
}

#div4 {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 53px;
    background-color: #FE69F9;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
      <div id="div1" class="cuadro"></div>
      <div id="div2" class="cuadro"></div>
      <div id="div3" class="cuadro"></div>
      <div id="div4" class="cuadro"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución que te comparto es que yo creé un 5o div y está sobrepuesto al 4o div y con un z-index mayor al 1er div. Para ello jugué con las coordenadas del **"Position: absolute"**.

Espero te ayude.
$4|u)0$

```css
#contenedor {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
.cuadro {
  width: 215px;
  height: 230px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.div1 {
    top: 0;
    left: 150px;
  background-color: #00D8FF;
  z-index: 4;
}
.div2 {
    top: 150px;
    left: 0;
  background-color: #25FE01;
  z-index: 3;
}
.div3 {
    top: 300px;
    left: 150px;
  background-color: #FE69F9;
  z-index: 2;
}
.div4 {
    top: 150px;
    left: 300px;
  background-color: #F7FE00;
  z-index: 1;
}
.div5 {
    top: 150px;
    left: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom: none;
  background-color: #F7FE00;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="contenedor">
      <div class="cuadro div1">1</div>
      <div class="cuadro div2">2</div>
      <div class="cuadro div3">3</div>
      <div class="cuadro div4">4</div>
      <div class="cuadro div5"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```